# SignalR: exclude non serializable types

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, signalr

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ThirdPartyClass { get; set; } // non serializable
}
```

I said "non-serializable" because when I pass my class to a SignalR client function in this way:

```
var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
var myData = new MyData();
// fill fields
hub.Clients.All.data(myData);
```

the call return error 500.
Removing the offending field it work as expected.

Please, note I'm *not* interested to pass to the client that field.

Right now I know two ways to solve this:

1. write a custom json serializer
2. create a shadow class with only the relevant fields, copy the values, and send this class to the clients

Both are uncomfortable when you have dozen of fields.
I'm wondering if there's some DataAnnotation I might use to exclude a field from serialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IgnoreDataMemberAttribute()` but I'm not sure if that would work with SignalR.

Your alternative if that doesn't work is the `JsonIgnore` annotation.

Lastly, there is also `ScriptIgnore`.

[IgnoreDataMember Class Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)